# Draw square function swift

Tags: swift, function, drawing

I'm trying to create a new `drawSquare` function that accepts a parameter for size. This will allow one function to create squares of multiple sizes!

This is the code that I wrote. I know I'm making a small mistake, please help.

```
func drawSquare(sideLength: Int) {
    move(sidelength) 
} 
drawSquare(sideLength: 150)
```

Comment: So what's the question? And what's `move`?

Comment: How do you know you are making a mistake? Is the error in compilation, or at runtime? Is it a behavioural problem?

Comment: Never mind I figures out the problem

Answer (score -2):

The correct format

```
func drawSquare(sideLength: Int) {

    move(steps:sideLength)
    rotate(degrees: sideLength)
    move(steps: sideLength)
    rotate(degrees: sideLength)
    move(steps: sideLength)
    rotate(degrees: sideLength)
    move(steps: sideLength)
}

drawSquare(sideLength: 90)
```